# Linux shell script: Pass variable from stdin to awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a comma-separated .txt file structured like this:

```
ABC,NAME1,LASTNAME1
DEF,NAME2,LASTNAME2
GHI,NAME3,LASTNAME3
```

When running:

```
$ ./script.sh file.txt

#!/bin/bash
awk -F, '/NAME1/{print $3}' "$1"
```

I get my desired output:

```
LASTNAME1
```

When trying to replace `NAME1` by passing a variable to `awk`:

```
$ ./script.sh file.txt NAME1

#!/bin/bash
awk -v n="$2" -F, '/$n/{print $3'} "$1"
```

I do not get any output at all. I checked, that `$2` entered in bash really is `NAME1`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable names in Awk are *not* prefixed with a `$`,
so it should be just `n` instead of `$n`.
Also, you cannot use variables inside a `/.../` expression.
You can write like this:

```
awk -v n="$2" -F, '$0 ~ n {print $3}' "$1"
```

Btw, if the `n` parameter should match the value in the 2nd column exactly,
then it's better to use an exact matching condition with `==` on `$2`:

```
awk -v n="$2" -F, '$2 == n {print $3}' "$1"
```

Comment: ah, I see! So, this awk command means: search in column 1 ($0) and if pattern (n) matches (~), print..." ? during my research, I also found, that $0 means line one? which is correct

Comment: @Shushiro `$0` means the entire current line.